# Select element in the same list as element with "title"

Tags: jquery, python, list, selenium, jstree

I have the following code:

```
<div id="filebrowser" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-grid-cell jstree-default jstree-checkbox-selection" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="-3" aria-busy="false" aria-selected="false">
    <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children" role="group">
        <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="-3_anchor" aria-expanded="false" id="-3" class="jstree-node  jstree-last jstree-closed" aria-busy="false">
            <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
            <a class="jstree-anchor jstree-grid-col-0" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="-3_anchor" title="/">
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-checkbox" role="presentation"></i>
                <i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>/
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c4dz.png)

For my Selenium testing I need to click on the `<i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl">`, which is marked red in the screenshot. I would like to click on this in the list that also has and `<a>` element that has a `title= attribute`. Is that possible?

For the background: I would like to select different files in given jstree and point on these files by setting their names as global values. If I would like to select `"/"`, `"etc/"`, `"testdirectory"` and then `"test_file.txt"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the `WebElement` represented as **`<i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl">`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@role='treeitem']/i[@class='jstree-icon jstree-ocl' and @role='presentation']").click()
```

But looking at the `HTML` seems we may have to invoke `click()` method on the `<a>` tag as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@role='treeitem']//a[@class='jstree-anchor jstree-grid-col-0']").click()
```

Comment: This works for this case, but is there a possibility to implement clicking on the element that as an a element with "title" attribute next to it ?
As shown below this doesn't work when there are multiple anchors.
[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/hkbc2q)

Comment: Any element which is **designed as interactive** can be **clicked**. Treat the **`Attributes`** just like ornaments. If my **`Answer`** have catered to your **`Question`** please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my **`Answer`** which is just below VoteDown arrow, so the tick mark turns green. Thanks